# Adding em tag on load to highlight but text not getting highlight

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding `em` tag on load to highlight text.

It highlights text in the below two cases:

`<em><span></span></em>`

`<em>Text</em>`

However, it does not highlight text for the cases:

`<em><p><span></span></p></em>`

`<em><blockquote><p><span></blockquote></p></span></em>`

How can I solve this? What mistake am I doing?

Below is the code I am using:

```
var s = window.getSelection();
    
function dig(el){
    $(el).contents().each(function(i,e){
        if (e.nodeType==1){
            // not a textnode
         dig(e);
        }else{
            if (pos<start){
               if (pos+e.length>=start){
                range.setStart(e, start-pos);
               }
            }
            if (pos<end){
               if (pos+e.length>=end){
                range.setEnd(e, end-pos);
               }
            }
            pos = pos+e.length;
        }
    });
}


var pos;

var start,end, range;
function highlight(element,st,en){
    range = document.createRange();
   
    start = st;
    end = en;
    pos = 0;
    dig(element);
    s.removeAllRanges();
    s.addRange(range);
    var ra = s.getRangeAt(0);
    var newNode = document.createElement("em");
    newNode.appendChild(ra.extractContents());
    ra.insertNode(newNode);
}
```

I think the `p` tag is creating an issue here, due to which text is not highlighted.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply but I cannot create a fiddle because the pattern of data I have in the live site is totally different. I hope you can do something with above code.

Comment: its simple if it is like <em><span></span></em> then all ok. But if it like <em><p><span></span></p></em> then em not applies on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The problem is in the last sample. The HTML is not well-formed here.
The order of closing the `blockquote` `p` and `span` tags is incorrect.

The correct way will be

```
<em>
  <blockquote>
    <p><span>Sample Text</span></p>
  </blockquote>
</em>
```

Here, [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1257mjr9/4/), where all the examples from your question work.

Ideally, `em` should be the innermost element and it should not wrap other HTML elements.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223903/discussion-on-answer-by-ihimv-adding-em-tag-on-load-to-highlight-but-text-not-ge).